# Background image under other buttons

Tags: android, layout

I'm new to android, i'm trying to make a MainActivity screen with 2 button, 1 is "For Parent" and 1 is "For Children". So far my layout is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:text="For parent"
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:text="For parent"
        android:id="@+id/children"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I do have a background image that I want it to be the background of this activity, and the 2 buttons will be on the top of it. How do i archive it? and what should be the size for the background image?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at [Drawable Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) at Android Developers. There they explain that

> A bitmap file is a .png, .jpg, or .gif file. Android creates a Drawable resource for any of these files when you save them in the res/drawable/ directory.

So, you should import your image and put it on your /res/drawable/ folder. Keep in mind different screen sizes.

The android xml notation you are looking for is called ***android:background***. In your code, it would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/your_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:text="For parent"
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:text="For parent"
        android:id="@+id/children"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Another alternative, would be adding a [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) that fill up the entire background (But this ImageView is affected by its parent LayoutParams, as Margin for example). Using ImageView will provide you more freedom to deal with the image,like, setting its ScaleType to fit the center of your Layout.

Answer (score 0):

It can be something like below (imageview is stretched to the entire view and set back, so it will be like background image):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="your_drawable"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:text="For parent"
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:text="For children"
        android:id="@+id/children"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the background attribute of your root ViewGroup.

Change this to

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

to this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType = "centerCrop"         
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is add the next line in the layout properties:

***"android:background="@drawable/image"***

And remember you need to put your background image into the drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/image" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:text="For parent"
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:text="For parent"
        android:id="@+id/children"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>    
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put image into `drawable` folder. Than add it as background to your `LinearLayout` with attribute `android:background="@drawable/your_image"`. You can place different image sizes into appropriate drawable folders such as `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi` etc. You can read about supporting different screens [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).
For simple colors and gradient you can use [Shape Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape), for real images i suggest you to add image view to your layout (`RelativeLayout` instead), set image as `ImageView`'s source and set appropriate `scaleType` (f.e. centerCrop).

Layout hierarchy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/your_drawable"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```